# Are my correlations significant or non significant?

Tags: self-study, correlation

I have 4 Pearson's r correlation. I used cor.test in R. My p values are super high and I am having trouble interpreting significance. I would say there is no significance in ANY of my 4 correlations. Am I wrong? Please help me confirm. I have been using p value interpreters, but I am not confident that I am right.

1)r= -.02, p value= .90

2) r=.14, p value= .43

3)r= -0.04, p value=.80

4) r=.11, p value= 0.5

Comment: That would be the standard interpretation, a high $p$-value in a situation like this is taken as a sign of no (linear) association.  I would also take a look at some scatter plots of the data.

Comment: Please say more about what is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask what you are going to do with the correlations? P-values can be very misleading, when you are working with correlations. If you simply try to uncover the degree of relation between the variables, @dsaxton's answer is sufficient. But if the purpose is to detect multicollinearity or prepare for a factor analysis or a cluster analysis, p-values are simply not the way to go.